# How to set up multiple adjacent forms using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have the following HTML using Bootstrap to style:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input></input> 
        </div>   
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input></input> 
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <div class='form-group'>
          <input type="checkbox"></input>
          </div>
         <div class='form-group'>
          <input></input>
          <input></input> 
         </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <div class='form-group'>
          <input type="checkbox"></input>
          </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <input></input>
          <input></input> 
         </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nv8aP/58/). What I am trying to do is set up a even 3 x 3 matrix with the input(checkbox included) with position (1,1) missing.

In addition to this I want the labels to sit to the left of the text inputs and remain there without shifting to the top of the first set of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by setting a minimum width on `form-group` and using that class consistently across the columns. Because the size needed to keep the label next to the input, you'd also need to adjust the column width; use `md` instead of `sm`.

```css
.form-group {
    min-width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class='form-group'><br /></div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input /> 
        </div>   
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input /> 
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class='form-group'>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <input /> 
         </div>  
        <div class='form-group'>
          <input /> 
         </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class='form-group'>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <input /> 
         </div>    
        <div class='form-group'>
          <input /> 
         </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```